# delayed_job daemon quitting on errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, daemon, delayed-job

I'm running the delayed_job daemon using daemon-spawn gem, however, whenever there is a database locked error or any other type of error for that matter, the delayed_job daemon stops/quits.  Is there any way to rescue these exceptions in the daemon?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's no code, no answer :)

Depending on your setup you can rescue errors:

```
class CrawlJob

  attr_accessor :site_id

  def initialize(site_id)
    self.site_id = site_id
  end

  def perform
    begin
      Site.find(self.site_id).crawl
    rescue
      # ... handle the error
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks Wukerplank.  This is the background task I'm running:                                                                 `Episode.delay.fetch_podcast_episodes(@podcast)`

Comment: Even when I put this in a rescue block, the delayed_job daemon still exits on a database locked error.

Comment: Could you post the code for fetch_podcast_episodes? I suppose the rescue block would have to go in there as this is the code that will be executed later and might fail.

Comment: Thanks so much Wukerplank.  I think I fixed it by adding another rescue block around the initial active record query of fetch_podcast_episodes.